# How to balance data when write overload is too heavy

Tags: mongodb

I deployed a sharded cluster of two shards with MongoDB version 3.0.3.
Unfortunately, I chose a monotonic shard key just like:
`{insertTime: 1}`
When data size was small and the write speed was slow, the balancer can balance the data between the two shards. But when the data size grows big and our write speed is much faster, the balancing speed is so slow.
Now, the hard disk's storage of one of the two shards called shard2 is near the limit.
How Can I solve this problem without stopping our service and application??

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you change your shard key while it's not too late to do so to avoid the preditable death of your cluster.

When a shard key increase monotonically, all the writes operations are sent to a single shard. Thus, this shard will grow then split into 2 shards. You will continue to hammer one of them until it splits again. At some point, you cluster won't be balanced anymore and your cluster will trigger some chunk moves and slow down your cluster even more.

> MongoDB generates ObjectId values upon document creation to produce a unique identifier for the object. However, the most significant bits of data in this value represent a time stamp, which means that they increment in a regular and predictable pattern. Even though this value has high cardinality, when using this, any date, or other monotonically increasing number as the shard key, all insert operations will be storing data into a single chunk, and therefore, a single shard. As a result, the write capacity of this shard will define the effective write capacity of the cluster.

You do not benefit from the good part of the sharding with this shard key. It's actually worst in performance than a single node.

You should read this to select your new shard key and avoid the typical anti patterns. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/

Comment: Thanks for @Polux ! If I choose a random shard key like hash value on insertTime, what will be the performance of range query on this key as we always count on insertTime??

Comment: I'm afraid the performance will be poor because with a hashed sharding key, you will have good performance on the writing operations because they are going to be evenly distributed to your shards but when you want to query for "the most 100 recents inserts" for example, MongoDB will have to run a scatter/gather operation on all the shards.
If it's the main use case you're trying to solve here, this is probably not the sharding key you should pick. You should take the shard key that will allow you to target a specific shard for each query. I don't know your model so it's difficult to say more.

Comment: Also, I'm really concern with this : _"Now, the hard disk's storage of one of the two shards called shard2 is near the limit."_
unless your machines are not identical, I don't see any reason for your disk space to be really different unless you touched the maxSize (for a shard) or the chunkSize.
Normally, the balancer makes sure that you don't have a difference bigger than 8 chunks of 64MB at all time in your cluster. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers! As our data volume is lage and the write overload is quite heavy, I think and actually the balancer can not catch up the write speed. I always type the command `sh.status()` and find that the difference of chunks between the two shards is often bigger than 8 and even any more.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a shard to the cluster to increase capacity.
From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-shards-to-shard-cluster/):

> You add shards to a sharded cluster after you create the cluster or any time that you need to add capacity to the cluster. If you have not created a sharded cluster, see Deploy a Sharded Cluster.
>
> When adding a shard to a cluster, always ensure that the cluster has enough capacity to support the migration required for balancing the cluster without affecting legitimate production traffic.

Comment: But the balancing speed is slower than the write speed and the shard key is monotonic ascending.  Is there any solution to change the destination of write option??

Comment: Yes, with a good shard key : you write into the chunk the data belongs to accordings to the [shard ranges](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.status/).
Mongodb gives priority to the writing operations. The chunk moves are done in background to try not to interfere too much with the performances. But here you are hammering only one shard so it's normal that your performances are actually worst than a single node...